# Apache httpd "Obsolete connection setting"

Tags: ssl, httpd.conf

I have an existing server that is using the following setting.

```
The connection to this site uses TLS 1.2 (a strong protocol), RSA (an 
obsolete key exchange), and AES_128_CBC with HMAC-SHA1 (an obsolete cipher).
```

If I want to change the key `exchange` and `cipher`, do I need to get a new certificate?

Answer (score 0):

The cipher is (mostly) unrelated to the certificate. Given that you are using a RSA certificate (since otherwise RSA key exchange would not be possible) you can switch to ECDHE key exchange. And instead of AES-128-CBC you might use AES-128-GCM or AES-256. For useful configurations you might use the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/).